# Reload html element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page which opens another page using window.open and does some work and refreshes whole parent page . Is it possible to refresh content of a div/table on parent page using JQuery/Javascript ?

FYI : Here the content of the div is not changing there is an image inside div which is edited by child window which I want to update but that image does not have unique id so I want to refresh whole div .

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `.load()` method of jQuery to quickly update the contents of a container

http://api.jquery.com/load

Simple as

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html', function() {
  alert('Load was performed.');
});
```

Comment: The only potential concern is caching, if the contents of the image change but the src doesn't.

Comment: @Mathew yup, if the URL is the same, then you'll need to add a random value at the end or something similar to force a new fetch

Answer (score 4):

Pure JavaScript (not JQuery) solution : wrap your div in an iframe, give it an id `myFrame`, then refresh it from the child like this:

```
parent.document.getElementById("myFrame").reload();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#myDiv", window.parent.document).load("page.html", function(){
    alert("Portion of page loaded");
});
```

The second parameter of $() is the context to search into. Default to document.

You can use .html() instead of .load() if you want reload from html string instead of using another page.